# Google Sheets - Group Users With >1 Attributes

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with a data of submission results. Some of data points available: name of submitter, date of processing, and results (approve/reject).

Here is a sample dataset:

[image]

Data is sorted by (in this order):

1. Name of submitter
2. Submission time of each person, in ascending order (e.g. Andy's 2 entries: first row rejected, second row approved.)

My goal : identify people who has been rejected AND tried submitting again AND eventually got approved.
Or an alternative 'filtering' statement = anyone who has BOTH approved AND rejected submissions.

So when applied to the data sample above::

[image]

Both Andy and Evan meets the criteria, since they both have been rejected (could be 1x or >1x), but eventually got approved.
People who got approved in their first try (David), or rejected but never got approved (Bill, Chris), would not be included.

Currently I only could achieve that by eyeballing the dataset, just like one might do on a small dataset such as above. However, I work with 10k+ rows in the actual dataset.

I managed to remove people who only have a single entry (regardless of approved status) since people who meet my criteria would have at least 2 entries.
I used highlight duplicate formula to color the duplicates, sorted the data by cell color, then remove the single entries.

When applied to the sample data above, I got:

[image]

My question is: is there a formula that could help me separate the Bills (multiple rejects) from Andys and Evans (people with 1 approve and at least 1 rejects) in a large dataset, without having to eyeball them?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I would use unique() to get a list of names then countif() or countifs() to evaluate further. these are functions in Excel.

Comment: Hi @SolarMike, thanks for the response!
Could you elaborate a bit more? Unique could help identify what unique values are present in the range. The range only has 2 unique values: approve and reject.

How do you think countif can help in this case? Count ifs:
- the person name is a certain value 'Andy' (I think it's doable)
- there are at least 1 approve and 1 reject in the Decision column (not sure how to do this, any ideas?)

Comment: Also, I did something similar already with pivot table: count how many entries each person has. However, I can't quickly distinguish which ones have at least 1 approved entry within the multiple entries.

Comment: you could use countif() with and() to make sure of at least 1 reject and 1 approve.

Comment: Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Solarmike, found a solution:

Use countifs to calculate the number of approve and rejects for each name.

[image]

Then filter out the ones with ApproveCount = 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A10),ArrayFormula(COUNTIFS(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A10),B2:B,"Reject")*(COUNTIFS(A2:A,UNIQUE(A2:A10),B2:B,"Approve"))>0))
```

[image]